# C# with Crypto-JS returning different results

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt in JS and also do the same in C# using AesManaged C# class and Crypto-JS JS library. This is supposed to be using AES-256.

The results come out to be very different and have spent hours trying to figure out what may be going wrong, I have also looked at similar questions but with no luck at all in figuring out what my code's specific issue is...

Any ideas what may be wrong with the code?

JS Code is below:

```
    // Function to encrypt
function encrypt(text) {
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encryption_key);
    var cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, encryption_key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).toString();

    return cipherText;
}

// Function to decrypt
function decrypt(cipherText) {
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encryption_key);
    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, encryption_key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    return originalText;
}
```

C# Code is below:

```
public static string EncryptData(string text)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the AesManaged
        // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
        // vector (IV).
        using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
        {
            myAes.BlockSize = 128;
            myAes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            myAes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(text, myAes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, AesManaged aesManaged)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, AesManaged aesManaged)
    {
        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transformaesManaged
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    // and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

Comment: `UTF8.GetBytes()` is the wrong way to get a Key (or an IV). I can't imagine a serious JS library doing the same.

Comment: But you will need the very detailed specs for CryptoJS to resolve this.

Comment: What does `toString()` return in your JS code? Could you print out an example ciphertext for us? How is your key generated in the C# code? That seems to be missing.